# Smooth shading in Unity

Tags: unity, lighting, fbx

I would like to have more higher poly sphere than in Unity standard sphere.

I have made sphere in Blender, set smooth and imported in Unity as fbx.

Now, I have problem that for every face there is a black border showed. It doesn't look very nice. How to fix that ?

[image]

Comment: I'm not sure whaf you mean by black border

Comment: In the image you see black edge of the faces on the sphere. I would like to be smooth so that polygons won't be visible.

Answer (score 1):

Read the error message at the bottom. You forgot to add Albedo UVs.